# Weird problem when moving objects

Tags: transforms

I have a simple blender file (the Pokémon models are copyrights of Game Freak). This is the original render:
[image: Original]
If I move any object, the others will completely bug out:
[image: Buggy 1]
[image: Buggy 2]
Here is my [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D0y3eFfTJ50qqHD7jonVKxCOmkrz3l5x/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *Proportional Editing* option (top header menu, blue circle), it acts on all the objects around the one you move.

[image]

Also, as Leander points out, keep in mind that if you move a rigged object instead of its armature, it might also deform.

Comment: Thats only a partial reason for the "bug out". The models deform because of the armature modifiers.

Comment: you mean if you move the object instead of the armature? Yes sure, but like any rigged object (with constraints)